# Excel coding using while loop

Tags: excel

so I have a loooot of work that I need to do and it's basically just capturing data that are in different excel tabs, so I have a formula that gets the values from each different excel tab and then arranges it in the order I need so that I can simply copy and paste now what I do is change ='Tank 3'!12 to ='Tank 3'!S12 then highlight each row and use find and replace to change 12 to 13, 14 , 15 etc as there a lot of rows worth data in each tab, I was wondering if i could use a while loop in excel to accomplish this? Instead of going through 42 rows manually using find and replace? Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Excel will change 12 to 13 when you drag the initial formula down.

Comment: true yes, but not if I add the dollar sign?

Comment: Then don't add the dollar sign. Why would you add it if you want the number change?

Comment: Because I have say 5 tabs, with the info being at the exact same spot in each tab but with different values , and it has to be in exact order, for example the first two rows will be from tab one the next 7 rows will be from tab 5 and the next 2 rows from tab 3 etc

Comment: if I don't add the dollar sign it will take me to the column but i want the next row